# Git repo branching mistake fix

Tags: git, github

I was trying to create a new branch from the master branch of my organization repository, and yet when I checked how this branch was, I found that it was some commits behind the master branch. I found that I had forgot to do a pull into my branch before creating that branch. Should I contact the admin of the repository before resetting it to the correct state, and what are the commands I should perform to get it in line with the latest commits?

Answer (score 2):

This command should rebase your current branch on top of the local `master` branch:

```
$ git rebase master
```

This assumes you pulled the changes on `master` already. Alternatively you can rebase directly on top of the remote branch after fetch:

```
$ git rebase origin/master
```

This assumes your remote is called `origin` (which is often the case).

Answer (score 2):

make sure you checkout into master and pull the changes using:

```
git pull
```

rebase with master

```
git rebase origin/master -i
```

force push your branch using

```
git push origin <your branch> --force
```

click on your commit to check that no files are different in your branch from master

Comment: I agree with this answer. Re-basing may have caused you to diverge from the remote branch, in which case a force push is necessary.  But there no need to make the re-base interactive.  I'd drop the "i", unless the op really wants to interactively re-base

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are correct.

If you just created your branches, then you could also just delete them and start over.

To delete your remote branch:

```
git push origin --delete <your branch>
```

to delete your local branch:

```
git branch -D <your branch>
```

You shouldn't need to contact the Administrator to delete branches that you created.